# How to use the creating class` methods from the created class?

Tags: c++, qt, methods, usability

I have a question:

I have a class **userinterface** that *has* a class **MoveSeries**. From MoveSeries I want to have access to the methods of my class userinterface. In this example I want to have access to the method get_MoveCurve_Delta() of userinterface. **How do I get access to the creating class (userinterface) from the created class (MoveSeries ?** I tried the Signal-Slot-Approach but since I have to use several methods of userinterface several times this makes lots of signal-slots...

here is my code:

Userinterface.h:

```
 class UserInterface : public QMainWindow
 {
     Q_OBJECT

 public:
     UserInterface(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
     ~UserInterface();
     ...
 private:
     double MoveCurve_Delta;
     MoveSeries *MOVE_SERIES  ;
 public:
     void set_MoveCurve_Delta( double val)     { MoveCurve_Delta  = val;}
     double get_MoveCurve_Delta()      { return MoveCurve_Delta  ;}
 }
```

Userinterface.cpp:

```
 UserInterface::UserInterface(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags) :          
 QMainWindow(parent, flags)
 {
     ui.setupUi(this);
     ...

     MOVE_SERIES = new MoveSeries( this);
 }
```

MoveSeries.h:

```
  class MoveSeries : public QDialog
  {
     Q_OBJECT
 public:
     explicit MoveSeries(QWidget *parent = 0);
     ~MoveSeries();
     ...
```

MoveSeries.cpp:

```
 MoveSeries::MoveSeries(QWidget *parent) :
 QDialog(parent),ui(new Ui::MoveSeries)
 {
     ui->setupUi(this);
     this->parent = parent;    
     parent->set-MoveSeries_Delta_Val();
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than assume that the parent QWidget in MoveSeries is UserInterface, you can also *require* that it is.

MoveSeries.h:

```
  class UserInterface; // only need a forward declaration

  class MoveSeries : public QDialog
  {
     Q_OBJECT
 public:
     explicit MoveSeries(UserInterface *parent = 0);
     ~MoveSeries();
     ...
     UserInterface * uiparent;
 }
```

MoveSeries.cpp:

```
 #include "Userinterface.h" // include the header where it is required

 MoveSeries::MoveSeries(UserInterface *parent) :
 QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::MoveSeries), uiparent(parent)
 {
     ui->setupUi(this);
     uiparent->set-MoveSeries_Delta_Val();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to cast the parent to the class you want:

```
static_cast<UserInterface *>(parent)->get_MoveCurve_Delta();
```

Bear in mind that this could be dangerous as it makes an assumption about the type of the parent.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It works !!!   Am I right to assume that the problem you are talking about is that parent is converted to userinterface* and if userinterface* is not the same typo of object I will run into problems?

Comment: Yes that's right. If you can look into restructuring your code so that the MoveCurveDelta is passed through a constructor or updated on child objects by the parent rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only `UserInterface` be the parent of `MoveSeries`, say so:

```
  explicit MoveSeries(UserInterface *parent = 0);
```

If you want *any* widget to be able to act as the parent, you cannot access `UserInterface` methods because the parent does not necessarily have them.